# Next.js: Calling router.push after API await resolves

Tags: next.js

I'm not really sure how to ask this question so I'll do my best to describe it:

I have two pages: Page 1 contains a document that requires approval and therefore I have an "Approve" button. The onClick function for the Approve button contains an Axios API call to generate *n* number of follow-on documents which, once created in the DB, I want to display on page 2.

I am using getServerSideProps in page 2 to fetch the follow-on documents from the DB to render in the page but the problem I am having is that router.push() in the page 1 Approve onClick function is being called before the API call has resolved resulting in page 2 getServerSideProps not returning any of the follow-on documents (unless I do a hard reload of page 2).

Here is the code for the onClick function:

```
const handleApproveClick = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const { data } = await axios.put(
        "https://blahblahblah.api.com/updateDocumentStatus/?docKey=sr&docType=stockrequests&status=Approved&docId=" +
          srId
      );

      const uniqueSuppliers = [
        ...new Set(
          stockRequest.sr_line_items.map(
            (supplier) => supplier.sr_line_item_supplier
          )
        ),
      ];
      console.log(uniqueSuppliers);

      const stockOrders = [];

      const createStockOrders = uniqueSuppliers
        .map(async (uniqueSupplier) => {
          const srFilterLineItems = await stockRequest.sr_line_items.filter(
            function (e) {
              return e.sr_line_item_supplier === uniqueSupplier;
            }
          );
          const soLineItems = await srFilterLineItems.map(
            (srFilterLineItem, index) => ({
              so_line_item_line_num: index + 1,
              so_line_item_sku_id: srFilterLineItem.sr_line_item_sku_id,
              so_line_item_description:
                srFilterLineItem.sr_line_item_description,
              so_line_item_uom: srFilterLineItem.sr_line_item_uom,
              so_line_item_uom_description:
                srFilterLineItem.sr_line_item_uom_description,
              so_line_item_price: srFilterLineItem.sr_line_item_price,
              so_line_item_quantity: srFilterLineItem.sr_line_item_quantity,
              so_line_item_total: srFilterLineItem.sr_line_item_total,
            })
          );
          console.log(soLineItems);
          const soCounter = await axios.put(
            "https://blahblahblah.api.com/counter/?counterName=so&venueId=RUL001"
          );

          setSending(true);

          const { data } = await axios.post(
            "https://blahblahblah.api.com/postDocument/?docType=stockorders",
            {
              so_id: `SO-RUL001-${soCounter.data.value.so_number}`,
              so_id_num: `${soCounter.data.value.so_number}`,
              so_sr_id: srId,
              so_total: round(
                soLineItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.so_line_item_total, 0)
              ),
              so_date_created: new Date(),
              createdAt: new Date(),
              so_delivery_date: new Date(),
              so_venue: "RUL001",
              so_supplier: uniqueSupplier,
              so_supplier_id: "Update1",
              so_status: "Created",
              so_payment_terms: "30 days",
              so_line_items: soLineItems,
            },
            {
              headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000/",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
              },
            }
          );
          console.log(data);
          await axios.post("/api/emails/newstockordertosupplier", {
            ...data[0],
          });
        })
        router.push(`/my-approvals/stock-request/${srId}/stock-orders`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

What is the best way for router.push() to trigger only after the handleApproveClick API calls have returned all the follow-on documents?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all I needed to do was wrap the createStockOrder function in a await Promise.all() and await router.push()

Also refactored the code to add the n documents to an array then call the API once instead of n times